# Алгоритм регрессии для логистичекой функции (4PL или 5PL)

Tags: алгоритм, математика, численные-методы

Необходим алгоритм регрессии (нахождения коэффициентов) для 4 или 5 параметровой логистической функции по методу наименьших квадратов.
F(x) = D+(A-D)/((1+(x/C)^B)^E)

Даю уточнения. Алгоритм нужен для решения задачи поиска концентраций вещества. Некоторые био/химические реакции (в данном случае ELISA) очень хорошо описываются логистичеким уравнением. В ходе реакции образуется цвет, считываемый фотометром. Калибровочная кривая часто имеет сигмовидную форму что дает повод для использовании логистичесой функции аппроксимации. Пример кривой приведен ниже:
[image: Standart curve]
<sub>(источник: [elisaanalysis.com](https://elisaanalysis.com/knowledge-base/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ELISA-Standard-Curve-Confidence-Intervals-Log-Scale.jpg))</sub>

Таким образом, даны от 4 до 10 точек, с координатами х и у, по оси ординат это оптические поглощения (варьирует от 0 до 4 как правило) а по оси абсцисс - концентрация вещества - (калибровочные точки).

Необходимо : найти коэффициенты логистической фукции (формула выше), максивально приближенно проходящей через данные точки.

Допускается алгоритм Ньютона для коэф A и D но С, В и Е должны быть найдены по методу наименьших квадратов.

Comment: Линеаризация тут вряд ли найдется - остается только решать жуткую систему нелинейных уравнений...

Comment: @Harry жуткая система у меня уже есть в готовом алгоритме (для нахождения коэф полинома или 3 степени). Я просто пытаюсь данное уравнение привести к полиному..

Comment: Вы еще учтите (почему-то даже в научных статьях это крайне редко учитывают), что линеаризация (да любое приведение к иному виду) добавляет весовые функции, так что найденные коэффициенты, строго говоря, **не** минимизируют именно сумму квадратов `y_i-f(x_i)`...

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае, задача решается поиском минимума 5-мерной функции, которая и будет суммой квадратов отклонений логистической функции от экспериментальных данных. Решаем методом Ньютона, благо функция "сумма квадратов отклонений" хорошо дифференцируется.
Проблема состоит в том, что метод Ньютона, очень чувствителен к выбору начального приближения. Подбор начального приближения очень сильно зависит полноты экспериментальных данных, и степени покрытия ими различных характерных областей целевой функции. Существуют разные методы их подбора, вплоть до применения нейронных сетей.

В данном случае, я бы посоветовал сначала зафиксировать параметры B=1, E=1(единственные безразмерные параметры в нашей функции), и подгонять только A, C, D. 
Как найти начальное приближение для A, C, D? Это зависит от полноты экспериментальных данных.

Например:

1) Если у нас много данных, во всех частях кривой то можно оценить асимптотические значения f(x)?

```
A = lim{x->0}( f(x) )
D = lim{x->inf}( f(x) )
C = root{x}( f(x)==(A+D)/2 )
B = f'(C) *C/(A-D)
E = 1
```

где f(x) - функция аппроксимирующая экспериментальные данные, например, скользящее среднее. Для вычисления f'(C), построим линейную аппроксимацию по нескольким точкам в окрестности x=C.

Получив начальное приближение, A,B,C,D,E нужно обязательно уточнить его, (например, методом Ньютона), это позволит избавиться от ошибок связанных с оценкой пределов функции.

2) Если экспериментом хорошо описана область x->0 берем несколько точек в окрестности x=0, аппроксимируем обычным полиномом, получаем приближенные значения F(0), F'(0), F''(0). Из аналитического дифференцирования имеем:

```
 F(0)=D
 F'(0)=(A-D)*-1/C
 F''(0)=(A-D)*2/(C^2)
```

Решив эту систему уравнений получим начальные приближения для A,C,D.
Дополним ее:

```
B=1 
E=1
```

И уточним Ньютоном...

3) Если хорошо описана область x->inf сделаем замену переменной y=1/x.
Для функции G(y)=F(1/y), найдем найдем производные в окрестности y=0, далее решим для G(0), G'(0), G''(0) систему уравнений, и далее аналогично случаю (2).

4) Если оба конца, описаны плохо, но хорошо описана окрестность точки перегиба нашей функции (x=C), то в качестве начального С, выбираем точку экстремума функции x*f'(x).

```
 С = root{x}(  x*f'(x) == 0 )
```

Аппроксимируем полиномом несколько точек из окрестности x=C, и находим таким образом приближенные значения F(C), F'(C).

```
F(C) = (A+D)/2
F'(C) = (A-D)*(-1/4)/C
```

Откуда находим начальные приближения для A, D.

```
B = f'(C) *C/(A-D)
E = 1
```

И далее Ньютоном ..

Comment: Уважаемый Chorkov, спаибо за очень подробную раскладку. Посмотрите пожалуйста вопрос еще раз, я сделал дополнения. Интуитивно чувствую что необходимо логарифмирование для приведения к решению наименьших квадратов для трехчлена (полином 3 параметр, его алгоритм у меня есть), и далее по Ньютону находить A и D. Но нехватка математичеких знаний тормозит.. Помогите пожалуйста логарифмировать и привести в полиномальный вид это уравнение, буду очень признателен!

Comment: В полиномиальный вид это уравнение не приводится. Увы. Ваш набор точек, если он типичный, хорошо укладывается в случай (2): возьмите первые 4-6 точек и аппроксимируйте кубическим полиномом от x (без логирифмирования!).  При подгонке Ньютоном, обязательно подгоняйте все 5 параметров разом. Способ "подогнать два оставшихся параметра" не пройдет. (Он даст на порядок менее точное решение, чем подгонка "всего сразу".)

Comment: Ясно. Попробую как вы сказали